# If the inclusion $X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A$ holds then does the inclusion $A\subseteq B$ even when $A$ and $B$ are not contained into $X$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

Let's we assume the inclusion
$$
A\subseteq B
$$
holds. So if $X\setminus B$ is empty then surely it is contained into $X\setminus A$ for any $X$; however if $x$ is in $X\setminus B$ then it is not in $A$ since otherwise it was in $B$: so we conclude that for any $X$ the inclusion
$$
X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A
$$
holds.

Now let's we assume the inclusion
$$
X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A
$$
for **some** $X$: so by what proved above we conclude that the inclusion
$$
A\cap X=X\setminus(X\setminus A)\subseteq X\setminus(X\setminus B)=B\cap X
$$
holds: so if $X$ do not contains $A$ and $B$ then it seems possible that $A$ is not contained into $B$ so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask for a counterexample, provided this exists. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $A=\{1,4\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: If $X$ is just any old set, not containing $A$ and $B$, then this definitely won't hold. For example, take $X=\varnothing$, and then $X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A$ will always hold.

Comment: $X=B=\{0\}$, $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the not trivial counterexample. :-)

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the counterexample. :-)

Comment: $X\setminus A\supseteq X\setminus B$ is equivalent to $A\cap X\subseteq B\cap X$.

Comment: @DumperDGarb You are right. Anyway for confirmation: if $A$ is contained into $B$ then $X\setminus B$ is contained into $X\setminus A$ for any $X$, right?

Comment: $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow A\cap X\subseteq B\cap X\Rightarrow X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A$.

Comment: @DumperDGarb Okay, thanks for the repliement. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X=\{0\}$, $A=\{1\}$, and $B=\{2\}$.